# Get ID of Img element which is inside the td of table Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, image, html-table, hover, closest

I have a table in which I got the `img` elements in each `td` (table is in the order of 2 rows and 2 Columns)
I have to get the `id` of the image on `Hover`

I used the `closest` selector in jQuery..
but not able to get the `id` of the `img` which I `hover`

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="../img.jpg" id="img_1"/></td>
        <td><img src="../img1.jpg" id="img_2"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="../img.jpg" id="img_3"/></td>
        <td><img src="../img1.jpg" id="img_4"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('img').closest('td').hover(function () {
        var id = $(this).parent('td').prev().children('img').attr('src').substring(0, 7);
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

Kindly help me with this issue.

Comment: can you share the html sample

Comment: do you want to hover td/img

Comment: try ` $(document).ready(function () {
     $('td:has(img)').hover(function () {
        var id = $(this).find('td').attr('id').substring(0, 7);
        alert(id);
    });
});`

Comment: What I understood is, you want to hover the image and and want to get its id. You can use `$(this).attr("id")`

Comment: <table>
<tr>
<td>
<img src='../img.jpg' alt='' id='img_1'/>
</td>

<img src='../img.jpg' alt='' id='img_2'/>
<td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<img src='../img.jpg' alt='' id='img_3'/>
</td>

<img src='../img.jpg' alt='' id='img_4'/>
<td>
</tr>
</table>

Comment: Hi shiju, actually i tried with $(this).attr("id") but when i try to get the result!..am getting it as "undefined"

Comment: hi arun !!, i want to hover on img which is in td bro!!

Comment: `$('img').closest('td').hover(function ()` sets a hover listener on a td element, so the `this` inside of there is for the td, not the img.

Comment: thanks guys for your concern...and arun!! thanks for your hint..i got the result when i used   var id = $(this).closest('td').find('img').attr('id');  have a gr8 day

Comment: @sai: Please do code formatting when you post question. It helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/syAQn/)
I think you have html is like this :

```
<table> 
    <tr> 
        <td> <img src='../img.jpg' alt='' id='img_1'/> </td>
        <td> <img src='../img.jpg' alt='' id='img_2'/> </td>
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
        <td> <img src='../img.jpg' alt='' id='img_3'/> </td> 
        <td> <img src='../img.jpg' alt='' id='img_4'/> </td>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

Script:

```
 $('td').on('mouseenter',function(){
    alert($(this).children('img').attr('id'));
});
```